# How can I aggregate changes between rows in Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have several columns that can be either 1 or -1

```
d = {'col1': [1, 1,-1,1], 'col2': [1,-1,1,1],'col3': [1,-1,1,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)

   col1  col2  col3
0     1     1     1
1     1    -1    -1
2    -1     1     1
3     1     1     1
```

I want to count the number of columns that have flipped sign on each row to give:

```
   NumFlipped
0           0
1           2
2           3
3           1
```

How do I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by flipped?  I'm asking because I'm confused. If you mean `-1`, then you've a confusion into. Your required table. Explain more plz.

Answer (score 0):

Try comparing `diff` with `0`, then `sum`:

```
df.diff().fillna(0).ne(0).sum(1)
```

Or we can compare `df` with its shift:

```
df.ne(df.shift().fillna(df)).sum(1)
```

Output:

```
0    0
1    2
2    3
3    1
dtype: int64
```